# What floor function identity makes this true: $(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor} = -2\lfloor x\rfloor + 4\left\lfloor\frac {\lfloor x\rfloor}2\right\rfloor +1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I know that the graph of these two functions is the same:

$$(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor} = -2\lfloor x\rfloor + 4\left\lfloor\frac {\lfloor x\rfloor}2\right\rfloor + 1$$

Both of them interchange sign at integer points in the same manner. I'm trying to figure out what identity allows them to be equal, though. I know that I cannot apply a logarithm as that wouldn't do any good. I'm just trying to figure out how I could relate this to floor as an identity rather than just two  alternate forms for the exact same function.

Comment: Just write $n$ instead of $\lfloor x\rfloor$, and you're halfway there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only property of the floor function you need to use is, for $n$ integer:
$$
\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor=
\begin{cases}
\frac{n-1}2&\mbox{if $n$ is odd}\\
\frac n2 &\mbox{if $n$ is even}\\
\end{cases}
$$
Prove the result by writing $n:=\lfloor x\rfloor$; then argue by cases.

Comment: Yeah, that's the identity. If there's a generalization to be made of the result you found, it might be that $f(n):= n-k\lfloor\frac nk\rfloor$ takes $k$ possible values, and will generate a periodic sequence of those values.